# Debugging separate parts of a process in two IDEs

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll, intel-fortran, delphi-10.1-berlin

In short, is it possible to debug separate parts of a process (an .EXE and a .DLL) in two IDEs at the same time?

To expand a bit further, I have a DLL written in Fortran and compiled (in VS2017) with debug information using the Intel Fortran compiler. I also have a Delphi EXE, compiled using Delphi 10.1. The Delphi EXE calls the Fortran DLL.

If I want to debug just the EXE I can do that in the Delphi IDE without any issue but understandably I can't step into any of the DLL code. Conversely, if I want to debug the DLL I can attach to the running EXE or have VS2017 launch the executable.

What I'd **like** to be able to do is step through the Delphi code (or have breakpoints hit) in its IDE and when a call is made to the DLL, be able to step through (or hit breakpoints) in that code in VS.

I did do a good bit of searching but couldn't find anything specifically trying to do this. Has anyone achieved the above? Is it even possible? Or does the DLL count as part of the original process and therefore attached debuggers will always be limited to 1 for the entire thing.

TIA